# SP 2013 Claims Authentication Provider and session management

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, claims-based-auth, session

This is regarding SP 2013 Claims Authentication Provider and session management.
We have ADFS (Ping Federate ) integration as IDP for trust validation.
We are facing issue in session sliding
 When we edit the document from Sharepoint the session times out after 5 mins. The SAML Token Life time is 10 mins (+/- 5) and Logon Token Cache Expiration windows is 1 second

So we expect the session to slide if the user activity happens within the approximate window of 5 mins ( SAML Token Life time ~ Logon Token cache)
But we are seeing the session expires and thus the user had to re-login. We could clearly see the token cache is not there and some how re-issue of token is not happening.

Please note that we use sign in URL as default _trust / default.aspx and NO Custom sign in provider implemented.